# Android Studio: Storing/Reading a Text File in a Project

Tags: java, android, database, android-studio, text-files

I know how to read from a text file under other languages such as Visual Basic and have learned how to in Java as well, but in Android Studio how would I accomplish this? Also, when working with Visual Basic and Java I always accessed the Text File form the computer, but in Android Studio is there a way to include the Text File in the project so that when the app is downloaded it comes with the text file? Furthermore, is the text file method the way to go when storing data or is their other methods? Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Look up how to use assets folder

Comment: @cricket_007 Is the assets folder where I place my text file?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the following code to read or write in a file in android.I have written the my code in android studio;

Here is my XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#008080"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Android File example"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="Write Text into File"
        android:onClick="WriteBtn"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Read Text From file"
        android:onClick="ReadBtn"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my Java File:

```
package com.example.sudiproy.fileexample;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText textmsg;
    static final int READ_BLOCK_SIZE = 100;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textmsg= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    }

    public void WriteBtn(){
        try{
            FileOutputStream fileOut=openFileOutput("myText.txt",MODE_PRIVATE);
            OutputStreamWriter outputWriter=new OutputStreamWriter(fileOut);
            outputWriter.write(textmsg.getText().toString());
            outputWriter.close();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File saved successfully!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void ReadBtn(){
        try{
            FileInputStream fileIn=openFileInput("myText.txt");
            InputStreamReader InputRead=new InputStreamReader(fileIn);
            char[] inputBuffer=new char[READ_BLOCK_SIZE];
            String s="";
            int charRead = 0;

            while ((charRead=InputRead.read(inputBuffer))>0) {
                // char to string conversion
                String readstring=String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer,0,charRead);
                s +=readstring;
            }
            InputRead.close();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Please do not forget to include the following permissions in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll check it out later tonight, some have been telling me SQlite is better than File so I might check that instead. What do you think? I'm reading sports statistics and organizing them in arrays under the team name.

Comment: Yes,you can use SQLite and if you are familiar with ORM tools in android you can use them too(ORM are more easy to use).In my opinion you can use Realm.Its an excellent tool in android to store,read and write data in .@Justin Macrae